# Using .indexOf on more than one url string

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, indexof

**I've got a function that runs when a page's URL ends in /about.html**

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('/about.html') > -1) {
        $("#logo-black").typed({
            strings: ["Nothing^450&Co^250.^500", "^800__^400&Co^600."],
            typeSpeed: 70,
            backSpeed: 100,
            callback: function() {
                $(".typed-cursor").css("display", "none"),
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.main-load').toggleClass('main-load-active'),
                    $('.nav-text').toggleClass('nav-text-active');
                },400),
                $('.nav-reveal').toggleClass('nav-reveal-active');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**But I'd like to apply this function to other pages (contact.html, etc).**

**How can I make .indexOf work with more than one string?**

Any help/advice/suggestions/constructive criticism is appreciated! 
I know enough to know that this is trivial, but I've been unsure as to what solution would work best here.

Comment: Try something like `/(about-html|contact.html)/.test(window.location.href)`

Comment: `['/about.html', '/contact.html', ... ].some(x => location.href.includes(x))`

Comment: string doesn't have a contains method @haim770 - did you mean `includes` - that wont work in Internet Exploder or Oprah

Comment: @JaromandaX, You're right. It's the console window that misled me because apparently StackOverflow define such `contains` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```js
console.log(window.location.href)
if (/(about.html|contact.html|js)/.test(window.location.href)) {
  console.log("Contains either: about.html OR contact.html OR js")
} else {
  console.log("Can't find either: about.html OR contact.html OR js")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where did `about-html` come from? did you mean `about.html` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Very true, honest type error :) Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks Carsten, I'll implement this and report back 